# Convert (x + y = z) to propositional logic formula for 8-bit numbers

Tags: propositional-logic, bit-manipulation, bit-blasting

(Note: this was asked in the cstheory stackexchange, but I was told this is a more appropriate place for it.)

I have three 8-bit 2's-complement numbers (X, Y, and Z). I want to find a propositional logic formula using only the variables (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>... x<sub>8</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>... y<sub>8</sub>, z<sub>1</sub>... z<sub>8</sub>), where x<sub>i</sub> is the i<sup>th</sup> bit of x which expresses the concept that X + Y = Z. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a formula in [CNF form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) by writing down a truth table (with $2^{24}$ rows) and then converting each row to a single clause.  This will yield a formula with $2^{24}$ clauses, but the method is straightforward.

If you want a shorter formula, I suggest using [logic synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_synthesis), e.g., [Quine-McClusky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm), [Espresso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer).

The usual path to get a small formula is to allow introduction of additional variables, build a circuit (e.g., an adder circuit followed by a comparator), then convert to a formula using the [Tseitin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation).  This yields much smaller formulas, but it requires introducing extra variables, which you said you don't want.